# Multiple jQuery Datepickers multiple forms

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using multiple forms within one page. All the forms use `datepicker` with the same settings. As I can not use the same `ID` on two elements, I'm having to replicate code. Is there a better way of doing this?

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/1112/

```
     $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        minDate: 0,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            var d = new Date(selectedDate);
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 90);
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option", "maxDate", d);
        }
    });
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        minDate: +1,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#datepicker1").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#datepicker3").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        minDate: 0,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            var d = new Date(selectedDate);
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 90);
            $("#datepicker4").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            $("#datepicker4").datepicker("option", "maxDate", d);
        }
    });
    $("#datepicker4").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        minDate: +1,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#datepicker3").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#datep

icker5").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: 0,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        var d = new Date(selectedDate);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 90);
        $("#datepicker6").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        $("#datepicker6").datepicker("option", "maxDate", d);
    }
});
$("#datepicker6").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: +1,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#datepicker5").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
$("#datepicker7").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: 0,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        var d = new Date(selectedDate);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 90);
        $("#datepicker8").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        $("#datepicker8").datepicker("option", "maxDate", d);
    }
});
$("#datepicker8").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: +1,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#datepicker7").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

Comment: But they don't have the same settings, they all do different things, and update different elements etc ?

Comment: @adeneo but they are the same for both forms. I could cut it in half at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they are all different, or at least the `close` callback and `mindate` is, you can define a common settings object, and use that in all of them to make it easier

```
var settings = {
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1
}
$(".datepicker1").datepicker($.extend(settings, {
    minDate: 0,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        var d = new Date(selectedDate);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 90);
        $(".datepicker2", $(this).closest('form')).datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        $(".datepicker2", $(this).closest('form')).datepicker("option", "maxDate", d);
    }})
);
$(".datepicker2").datepicker($.extend(settings, {
    minDate: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $(".datepicker1", $(this).closest('form')).datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }})
);
$(".datepicker3").datepicker($.extend(settings, {
    minDate: 0,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        var d = new Date(selectedDate);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 90);
        $(".datepicker4", $(this).closest('form')).datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        $(".datepicker4", $(this).closest('form')).datepicker("option", "maxDate", d);
    }})
);
$(".datepicker4").datepicker($.extend(settings, {
    minDate: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $(".datepicker3", $(this).closest('form')).datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }})
);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/1114/)

Comment: I've edited my jsfiddle to make it more clear, Thanks, but this will not work, as in my example the user has been disabled from selecting an end date earlier than the start date. Unfortunately your examples lacks this function i think?

Comment: My current example - DEMO jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/1112 if you select a date from the first input field and then try and select a date from the second input field. It will restrict you to future dates only.

Comment: Oh, I see, you've completely changed the fiddle, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

[Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/1111/)

You can use class:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date_1" />
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date_2" />
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="date_3" />

$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: +1,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#OutwardDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will not work, as in my example the user has been disabled from selecting an end date earlier than the start date. Unfortunately your examples lacks this function

Answer (score 0):

Set a css class on each of the elements and call .datepicker() against that class. For example, $(".dateField").datepicker({...});

Answer (score 0):

Try using a class and set the datepicker accordingly instead of some single ID's.

I have used four classes because you have different options and different actions in the `onClose` event.

Code:

```
$(".datepicker1").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: 0,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        var d = new Date(selectedDate);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 90);
        $("#DateTo").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        $("#DateTo").datepicker("option", "maxDate", d);
    }
});
$(".datepicker2").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: +1,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#DateFrom").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
$(".datepicker3").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: 0,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        var d = new Date(selectedDate);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 90);
        $("#ReturnDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        $("#ReturnDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", d);
    }
});
$(".datepicker4").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: +1,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#OutwardDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A6pe6/

Comment: Thanks, but this will not work, as in my example the user has been disabled from selecting an end date earlier than the start date. Unfortunately your examples lacks this function

Comment: I can't this functionality in you example. Can you show me it?

Comment: DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/1112/ if you select a date from the first input field and then try and select a date from the second input field. It will restrict you to future dates only.

Answer (score 0):

Use **common class name selector** instead of different ID's. Using multiple ID's may utilize CPU time.

```
$(".YourCommonClassName").datepicker({
//DataPicker parameters..
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will not work, as in my example the user has been disabled from selecting an end date earlier than the start date. Unfortunately your examples lacks this function